# Redshift: Performance wise Is storing delimited values in a single column ever preferable to normalizing them out to another table?

Tags: database-design, redshift

I have been looking at increasing the performance of some tables that have been uploaded to a redshift database. One of the columns in a table has many delimited values which need to be split out and queried at runtime. The table has around 30 million rows and there would be on average 10 delimited values in this particular column.

Coming from an OLTP background my instinct is to normalize these values out to another table. However, I have seen various posts that suggest that this is not the way to go. Looking for some advice

Answer (score 1):

In a word, **NO!**

You should not breach [Codd's Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules) unless you have no choice but to do so.

I fail to see what performance gains you will obtain by having to parse strings over having an [Associative Entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) (AKA joining, bridging tables or mapping - amongst others) and using SQL `JOIN`s.

Most importantly from an RDBMS perspective, this allows you to enforce DRI (Declarative Referential Integrity) constraints on your data. DRI is your [friend](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/208850/using-rdbms-with-pseudo-foreign-keys-vs-using-nosql-solutions/208875#208875).

From the link:

> There are old-wives' tales about FKs being unnecessary overhead. This
>   notion was kept alive by the fact that (for good, but probably now
>   legacy, notably space, reasons) some RDBMSs did not/don't
>   **automatically** create indexes on Foreign Key fields (this **should** be done in the majority of cases). This led to the mistaken view that Foreign Keys were overhead without benefit which is **not**
>   true for the **vast bulk** of use-cases!

p.s. you mention that `I have seen various posts that suggest that this is not the way to go`- where are these references? I doubt if they'll stand up to much scrutiny!

Comment: I think you're still correct, but it may be important to note that Redshift doesn't support indexes, and therefore the whole argument is moot.  [Check here for things Redshift doesn't support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html)